# reading and printing text file from a website url line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, text, python-requests

I have this code here:

```
url = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deppokol/testrepo/main/testfile.txt")
File = url.text
for line in File:
    print(line)
```

The output looks like this:

```
p
i
l
l
o
w
```

and so on...

Instead, I want it to look like this:

```
pillow
fire
thumb
```

and so on...

I know I can add end="" inside of print(line) but I want a variable to be equal to those lines. For example

```
Word = line
```

and when you print Word, it should look like this:

```
pillow
fire
thumb
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

response is a `str` object which you need to `split()` first as:

```
import requests
url = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deppokol/testrepo/main/testfile.txt")
file = url.text.split()
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. This fixed my problem :D I tried using .split("\n")

Answer (score 1):

`.text` of `requests`' response is `str`, you might use `.splitlines` for iterating over lines as follows:

```
import requests
url = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deppokol/testrepo/main/testfile.txt")
for line in url.text.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Note that `.splitlines()` deals with different [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), so you can use it without worrying about what newlines exactly are used (using `.split("\n")` is fine as long are you sure you working with Linux-style newlines)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do `for line in url.text` because `url.text` is not a `IO` (`File`). Instead, you can either print it directly (since `\n` or the line breaks will automatically print as line breaks) or if you really need to split on new lines, then do `for line in url.text.split('\n')`.

```
import requests
url = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deppokol/testrepo/main/testfile.txt")
for line in url.text.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```

Edit: You might also want to do `.strip()` as well to remove extra line breaks.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [split("\n")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
import requests

for l in requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deppokol/testrepo/main/testfile.txt").text.split("\n"):
  print(l)
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/bd525f5d95)